# Getting an "syntax error unexpected IF" when using IF statement

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT IF((SELECT id FROM users where store='XXX' limit 1) IS NULL, null, (SELECT id FROM users where store='XXX' limit 1))  INTO @user_id;

select @user_id;

INSERT INTO `orders`(`user_id`)VALUES(@user_id);
```

I need is that when @user_id is NULL I don't want to insert into my table orders. If I put an if else statement above the insertion statement,I'll get an error saying that "syntax error unexpected IF".

Comment: is this a procedure or function or what?

Comment: hm.. direct query execution

Comment: im using workbench.. its a direct query execution...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to check a condition and do an action depends on is not null. Like this, please try: select 'xxx' into @user_id ; if(@user_id is not null) then select 1 as ok; end if;

Answer (score 0):

Use IFNULL function, this way:

```
SELECT IFNULL(condition, value_if_condition_is_null)
```

In your query, something like:

```
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT id FROM users where store='XXX' limit 1), (SELECT id FROM users where store='XXX' limit 1))) INTO @user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I need to check a condition and do an action depends on is not null.

Like this, please try: 

select 'xxx' into @user_id ;
if(@user_id is not null)
then
select 1 as ok;
end if;

Comment: it's in the answer: SELECT IFNULL(condition, value_if_condition_is_null)

Comment: or just select, in your app code check if null or empty query result, and write and if ... else ...